# Is it possible to optimize R2 in Machine Learning models automatically?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm using regression algorithms in Python. I know in order to improve the R2 score one can do some adjustment to models like playing with hyper-parameters, ensemble models, changing train-test size, using ensemble models ,so on.
I'm wondering if there are methods to do some of the above operations automatically to get best possible R2 score instead of doing this manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hyper-paremeter tuning I like the GridSearch and RandomizedSearch from the [scikit-learn library](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html). You can use those to automatically search through a range of hyperparameter values and find the combination that results in the best R2 score.

I have also read nice things about [auto-sklearn](https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/master/), but haven't tried it myself yet.